# Dynamically start new Docker containers when needed?

Tags: docker

Does exist any component that monitors usage of a server, of a resource or anther Docker instance(s) and starts new Docker containers when more resources are needed?

Docker containers may or may not be deployed on the same Server.

For example :

1) when a message queue grows too fast, other Docker containers that  listen that queue are started to help consuming the messages.

[image: Dynamic docker containers listening a Queue]

2) when too many request are made to a server throug a load balancer, other docker instances are run..

[image: Autostarted Docker behind Load Balancer]

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?  I'm especially interested in "scenario 1" above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing here is part of *orchestration*. Several tools exist for that, the best-known being [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) and [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how these tools might be used to solve the problems in the question?